# Coded ui does not recognizing exact window when same website is opened in multiple window of same browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, automated-tests, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests, browser-automation

I am using vsts 2012 for coded ui automation. I am facing scenario like ..we have web application deployed on azure. Now that application has different user roles ...while performing some activity....the respective activity should be carried out by multiple user on multiple window of IE...or we can say multiple tab..here..............so when i opens the application in two window IE using coded ui....when i tried to perform some coding action ...it always point/refers to same window....I tried to look into search & filter property ...for same control ...i found all properties are same ...hence can not identify which window...to click ??

my requirement is like :

When i opens 3/4 window using coded ui automation ...when i want ...user should have clicked on control of first window ...then that should be happen....when i thought now user should have refer window 4 then that should work ....

So how can i differentiate various window and then navigate users to required window ...please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you require many browser windows open at once, you'll need to create a way to pass in the browser window on the control in question.  For example, you can create your browsers like this:

```
BrowserWindow window1 = BrowserWindow.Launch(yourUri);
BrowserWindow window2 = BrowserWindow.Launch(yourUri);
BrowserWindow window3 = BrowserWindow.Launch(yourUri);
BrowserWindow window4 = BrowserWindow.Launch(yourUri);
```

Then, to get your object, you'll have to pass in the BrowserWindow object as a parameter in the method.

```
public HtmlHyperlink MyLink(BrowserWindow parentWin)
{
    HtmlHyperlink target = new HtmlHyperlink(parentWin);
    target.SearchProperties[yourprop] = "value";
    return target;
}
```

This way, when you call that object, you'll have it pointing to the correct window.

```
Mouse.Click(MyLInk(window3));
```

Comment: Hi Ryan Cox,  I have tried using same code ...while doing so .. i already kept 2 windows opened and again from automation i opened 4 . So while clicking it is giving me exception like --->The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties.......When we launches window using BrowserWindow ...then using which property it is keeping track of window...because while debugging i observed all values of window1, window2...not found any difference ..thats wahy it is getting confused ..please correct me if i am doing wrong

Comment: Then you could possibly use the method suggested by kida in this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522114/interacting-with-multiple-instances-of-an-application-in-coded-ui.  There, you specify the difference on the Instance property and set them to the object before using them in your tests.

Comment: Yes thanks for the help ...i tried with given code related instance property but results are not consistent ......................................................................var a1 = new UICalculatorWindow();
a1.SearchProperties["Instance"] = "1";
var a2 = new UICalculatorWindow();
a2.SearchProperties["Instance"] = "2";
a1.Find();
a2.Find();.......................................Is ther any custom method which can help me ...plz